# parameters not passing back from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections

I'm having trouble passing back some data as part of a collection_select dropdown and need help. The collection_select is part of a form to populate an order:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
```

The collection_select is supposed to show a list of possible payment types, pulled from a payment_type model, and use those to populate parameters for the @order instance.

Model 'order' has an integer 'payment_type_id' and this association:

```
belongs_to :payment_type
```

Model 'payment_type' has a string 'name', and this association:

```
has_many :orders
```

Here's the collection_select part of the form:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :pay_type_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select(:payment_type_id, @pay_type_collection, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Choose one'})%>
</div>
```

Here's the segment of the 'new' action in orders_controller.rb that creates the form:

```
@order = Order.new
@pay_type_collection = PaymentType.all
```

Here's the part of the 'create' action that accepts the form:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
respond_to do |format|
```

etc

Here's what I know:

- The drop-down displays the correct options listed in my payment_type model. It does it with no fields_with_errors in the page source.
- The debugger shows that (order_params) passes other parts of the form (text areas, etc) but not the collection_select data.
- This results in the following error when the Submit button is hit: "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"

Can someone please help me understand how to get my collection_select parameters back to the controller? I can't find the silver bullet in any of the similar questions about collection_select.

Comment: Could you show us what is in order_params, type raise order_params.inspect above @order = Order.new(order_params)

Comment: Sure thing. This comes back:

{"name"=>"Test name", "address"=>"Test address", "email"=>"testmail@testmail.com"}